# Running multiple jQuery libraries in parallel - how to tell if all libraries are loading?

Tags: jquery

I work on a site that runs the 1.3.2 jQuery library and I can't change or update that.  I frequently get requests for sliders or interactive functionality that requires a newer library, so I use noConflict.

I'm running into an issue with getting Bookblock to work on the site.  [You can see it here.](http://cookware.lecreuset.com/cookware/content_1cast-iron-guide-sizes_10151_-1_20002)  I can get it to work on other sites, so I don't think it's a problem with the code, but there aren't any error messages in the console (FF) to tell me why it's not working. I have a few questions:

- How can I tell if the 1.9.1 library is actually being read by the browser? I see it the Scripts panel in FF but if I update all the references to 1.3.2 to 1.9.1 in on my local machine, it works OK. So I wonder if it's not loading properly?
- When I look at the scripts panel, I see 3 other versions of the library running! I know where the 1.7.2 reference is coming from but not sure where it is pulling 1.4.2 or 1.7.1. I did a view page source and searched for these libraries and didn't find them. How can I figure out where these scripts are being called?
- Bookblock seems to work with 1.7.2 ([see here](http://lcoawebservices.com/mariner/index.html))so I tried removing the 1.9.1. reference all together to eliminate one more issue, since upgrading the 1.3.2 is not truly an option, but then several other things on the site break, such as the language selector at the top and email optin.

I am using noConflict in another content area of the site, so I also tried using jq191 instead of $j since that is being used elsewhere. That didn't help.

The issue is not with Bookblock, but rather how to use these newer plugins on the site...there are big plans for fancy sliders and lookbooks for holiday and I need to figure out how to execute.

Any ideas? I'm at my wits end with this and have no one in house to assist.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using some kind of CMS which perhaps loads jQuery? If so maybe look at the documentation for that to see how it loads jQuery?

Can you put an alert() in the 1.9.1 library and see if you see that? A bit basic I know but..

I don't think noConflict is your answer; it just returns $ to anything else using it.

$().jquery; will give you the version so maybe you can use that in your code to check for which version is being used at the point it is being used?

This question seems to address managing more than one jQuery instance with different variable names for each version:

[Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

This is a little tool which allows you to use a specific version of jQuery specifically for use with certain plugins etc:

https://github.com/quickredfox/jQuery-Quarantine However; note that the author no longer recommends its use.

Can you get it down to two versions? 1.4.2 for all the old plugins which you don't want to update and the latest version for newer plug-ins?

--JustinWyllie

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have to keep 1.3.2 in there for sure, I don't even know what is using 1.4.2 or why it's being called. Wish I could figure that out. I am such a newbie - how do I put an alert into the library to see if I see that? Happy to try.

Comment: also, I've seen that question before and that is how I have successfully used no conflict in the past with other scripts that require newer versions of jQuery. I don't know why these plugins are giving me so much trouble. I've tried 3 now and none will work.